# can anyone explain how to find the answer?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I'm having trouble finding the answer to this question I would like to know how to find the answer
[image]

Comment: Hint: start by computing the area of the whole "pie piece," which should be a fraction of the area of the whole circle. Then, compute the area of the triangle contained inside that pie piece and subtract.

Comment: outside links are frowned upon. please post all relevant material in the body of your question.

Comment: @Matt how would you do that?

Comment: @john_01 What part troubles you?

Comment: this is clearly a homework question and should be marked as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $68.9^{\circ}$ is $\frac{68.9}{360}$ of the whole circle; Since the circle has radius $9.28$, we find it has area

$$A_{\mathrm{circle}} = \pi r^2 = (9.28)^2\pi = 86.1184\pi$$

Thus, by multiplying by the fraction of the circle, we get that the area of the sector shown in the picture is.

$$A_{\mathrm{sector}} = \frac{68.9}{360} \cdot 86.1184\pi \approx 51.78$$

Now, we must find the area of the triangle. The height of the triangle will be $r \cdot \sin \theta$, or $9.28 \sin 68.9$, and the base length is obviously $9.28$. Thus, the area of the triangle is

$$A_{\mathrm{triangle}} = \frac{1}{2} b \cdot h = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 9.28 \cdot 9.28 \sin 68.9 \approx 40.1742$$

Thus, the area of this sliver of the circle is

$$A = A_{\mathrm{sector}} - A_{\mathrm{triangle}} \approx 51.78 - 40.1742 = 11.6057 \approx 11.6$$